# Solution to avoid static variables

Tags: c#, oop

In my solution, I have an `Object Class` with a `Copy()` that copies an `XElement` from an XML file to another.

Now, I recursively call `Copy()` because I need to send `Objects` that are within the current `XElement`. During the process, I extract the `value` of a particular `attribute` that will be updated.

Now, the only way that I found to do this, was extracting all these values and storing them in a `static variable` that won't be altered every time that a new instance of the `Object` is generated.

So, basically I have:

```
public class Item
{
    public XElement Element;

    private static readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> Ids = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    public String Copy(){

        //Recursively get all the OldIds from the current Element

        //populate the List with oldIds and ""

        //generate newId for this

        //update List that matches the OldId and put the newId

        //Update the Element

        //Transfer Element

        return newId;      
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to avoid using the `static List`?

Thanks

Comment: Calling it a **global** variable may be misleading. In C++, a global variable does not exist in a class, and in C#, a global variable isn't allowed.  You may want to call it a **static** variable just to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to make the method not be recursive, but instead be iterative.  You can write a general purpose tree traversal method to traverse your XML tree, and then call it on an element that you have, allowing you to populate your list without requiring any state shared between method invocations.

Here is a simple method to traverse a tree:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(source);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

You can then call that method on your element to get the whole tree of child elements:

```
XElement element = GetElement();
var tree = new[] { element }.Traverse(e => e.Elements());
```

Comment: Sounds great. But, at the end I also want to transfer those Items. That's why I am calling Copy again for them.

Comment: @LuisLavieri So then transfer all of the items in a loop, rather than using recursion.  A simple `foreach` lets you execute code for each of these items.

Comment: Yes. I suppose so :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Overload the Copy method to accept a list as the argument.

```
public String Copy(List<Tuple<string, string>> Ids) {}

public String Copy() {}
```

Comment: More than overloading, I considered optional arguments. Thanks